# Should user be able to scroll a web page while a modal is active?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, scrolling, modal-dialog

As far as best practices are concerned, should user be able to scroll the page while a modal is active?

Comment: This is really broad. Is there a specific example of this that you could ask about?

Comment: If you can guarantee the modal will always fit within the confines of the current viewport, then no. If not, yes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The entire point of a modal is that the **user needs to focus on that task before doing anything else.**

> Modality is most appropriate when:
>
> - It’s critical to get the user’s attention.
> - A task must be completed (or explicitly abandoned) to avoid leaving the user’s data in an ambiguous state.

Considering this, I would say it would be **counter intuitive** to let the user perform any action outside of the modal. If you still feel the need for letting the user work in the background, then you should re-evaluate the need for a modal.

---

I pulled the [guideline for modal from the iOS HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html), but, it is applicable even in web scenario.

Answer (score 3):

In normal modal use, the **page behind is currently "out of scope"** for the task at hand and should be considered inactive.

If your modal requires visibility to the page behind, it probably shouldn't be a modal. Consider expanding the content directly onto the page instead.

Answer (score 1):

**If there is scrollable content within the modal dialog box, then no**, scrolling should be disabled in the main window. (This is to avoid double scrolling from the user having their cursor in the wrong place.)

**If there is no scrollable content, then I think it depends on the context**. If there's something asking me to sign up or preventing me from proceeding without taking action in the modal, being able to scroll is nice. It allows users to get a "sneak peek" of what they can see if they were to follow your CTA.